# 404 error Spring MVC

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, spring-mvc

I have written a Spring MVC application which displays report of Test cases and suites run  in XML view.I have written the model class which is fine and I have written the following files but there's some problem with Handler Mapping i guess

**My controller.java class looks like this**

```
package com.DrAssist.Fitnesse.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.DrAssist.Fitnesse.model.Suite;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Suite/{name}")
public class XMLController {

    @RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "content-type=application/xml")
    public @ResponseBody Suite getSuiteInXML(@PathVariable String name) {

        Suite suite = new Suite("1",name,"3","Test1","4","5","7","9","550");

        return suite;

    }

}
```

**My web.xml file looks like this**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**and dispatcher-servlet.xml file looks like this**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.DrAssist.Fitnesse.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!--  
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

    <bean id="xmlViewer" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                <property name="classesToBeBound">
                    <list>
                        <value>com.DrAssist.Fitnesse.model</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    -->

</beans>
```

I am getting a 404 error with console showing error as

**No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/Suite/suite1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'**

Please advice It seems the request not getting through from SpringMVC part of /SpringMVC/Suite/suite1] itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: One more thing I would like to add is I have imported a program from Mykong made it work and then made changes to the same code according to my requirements.Does that affect the build and is it one of the reason why it is not running as it should.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `{name}` path variable in both `@RequestMapping`. Try to leave the first just as `@RequestMapping("Suite")`.

Comment: I tried with many permutations and combinations but it didnt work.My project name is SpringMVC and hence my URL looks like http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/Suite/suite1.I even tried using SpringMVC but it didnt work.My Controller currently stands like this

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work since the log statement is written in `DispatcherServlet` and are very well hard coded in there. There is very little you can do about it except replicate `DispatcherServlet` replacing the code which generates the error response code and instead redirect it to desired output.

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml you declared the dispatcher as mvc-dispatcher and the spring config file name you gave is dispatcher-servlet.xml it should be mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

if you have already write

```
@RequestMapping(value="{name}"
```

Than you not need to write this ,this is wrong .Please change

```
@RequestMapping("/Suite/{name}")
```

write instead

```
 @RequestMapping("/Suite")
```